# Other than the apple developer forums, where can I go to get technical answers for stuff in iOS betas?

Tags: ios, objective-c, resources

I'm curious to know where others have gone for resources related to APIs and new features released in iOS betas, other than the dev forums.

I realize I can't talk about the betas themselves, but I have very specific technical questions and I've found the docs are very limited at this stage. What are my other options?

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of questions and answers for iOS8 on Stackoverflow—1,651 results as of right now. Apple revised the NDA restrictions so you can discuss the APIs. You still can’t “ post screen shots, write public reviews or redistribute any pre-release Apple Software or services”. Refer to this link: http://oleb.net/blog/2014/06/apple-lifted-beta-nda/ for more.